# Scanf() requiring to input data twice. Why?

Tags: c, scanf

```
char username[50];

char exit_call[50] = "exit";
printf("[Enter Command]:");

scanf("%s", username);


if (strcmp(exit_call, username) == 0) {
    exit(0);
}

write(sock_fd, username, 50);

char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];

//Initialize the file descriptor set fdset
fd_set read_fds;
// Then have zero bits for all file descriptors
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
```

I don't understand why I have to press `enter` twice for my program to read the input. I am trying the input "hello".

Edit: added extra code

Comment: Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without an MCVE and knowing the exact input it's hard to help you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Its because of `write(sock_fd, username, 50);`, which writes to the server. How can I make this nonblocking?

Comment: The `write` call should have nothing to do with the problem you have. But since we don't have all information (in the form of an MCVE and the input) then of course it's a possibility. And if you search for *non-blocking sockets* you should get several thousands of hits about it. Not that it really matters, since 50 bytes will be passed through the local system pretty quickly.